# Unable to call report from oracle forms

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms, oraclereports

```
      DECLARE
        report_id Report_Object;
        ReportServerJob VARCHAR2(254);
        BEGIN
        report_id := find_report_object('REPORT18');
        SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_COMM_MODE,SYNCHRONOUS);
        SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESTYPE,CACHE);
        SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id, REPORT_DESFORMAT, 'PDF');
        SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_SERVER,'izvjestaj_rep');
        ReportServerJob := run_report_object(report_id);
        END;
```

[image]

*When i run this form i get error unable to run report, so i think this
trigger should be alright but i cant call report, So anyone knows what
could be problem here ? Thanks*

Comment: It looks alright, is request reached report server? Maybe this report does not exist or could not be found?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of unable report load can be:

- Misplacement of report directory within the registry.
- Report can be loaded ( try to compile the report in the same version of the forms. ie: if the form is in 6i the report should be in Reports Builder 6i).
- Report server can be inactive or having errors on your machine or server.